# Power Automate - sends incomplete excel file using Send Email (v2) from OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, power-automate

I am using Power Automate - which does something like below:

1. Report is generated from `Canvas App` which calls the flow.
2. Based on passed filters from canvas app - populate the `Fetchxml` & retrieve records from `dataverse`.
3. Use "File Content" of the pre-defined excel format (tables and columns mentioned in it) to create a new excel file in `OneDrive Business`.
4. Populate the excel cells with data fetched in step 2 above.
5. Send an email with attachment - the populated file.

**Issue**: It is sending a generated file as attachment but adding only a single row. Despite the reality that the file with same name - saved in OneDrive has more than one field.

[image: Part I]

[image: Part II]

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a "Delay" of 30 seconds before step `Get file content` and it seems working fine with that.